Unable to Initialize and Start MySQL in XAMPP on Windows 11 - Can't Connect to MySQL Server (10061)
I'm trying to set up MySQL on XAMPP on my Windows 11 machine, but I'm encountering persistent issues that I can't resolve. Here is a detailed account of what I've done and the errors I'm seeing.

Stopped XAMPP Services:

I used the XAMPP Control Panel to stop Apache and MySQL services.
Verified no mysqld processes were running using Task Manager.


Removed Existing MySQL Data Directory:

Command:
cd C:\xampp\mysql
rmdir /S /Q data
mkdir data




Initialized a New MySQL Data Directory:

Command:
cd bin
mysqld --initialize-insecure --datadir=C:/xampp/mysql/data




Attempted to Connect to MySQL:

Command:
mysql -u root


Error received:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)





Additional Information:

Windows Version: Windows 11 Home 64-bit
XAMPP Version: 8.2.12
Control Panel Version: 3.3.0 (Compiled: Apr 6th 2021)
MySQL Version: MariaDB 10.4.32 (bundled with XAMPP)

MySQL Error Log (relevant entries):
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.32-MariaDB-log source revision c4143f909528e3fab0677a28631d10389354c491 as process 7140
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.3
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 64M, instances = 1, chunk size = 64M
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Resizing redo log from 2*50331648 to 2*16777216 bytes; LSN=47056
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting to delete and rewrite log files.
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 16777216 bytes
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 16777216 bytes
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 to C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile0
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=47056
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.32 started; log sequence number 47056; transaction id 8
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240613 14:25:15
2024-06-13 14:25:15 6 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1017: Can't find file: '.\mysql\' (errno: 2 "No such file or directory")
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2024-06-13 14:25:15 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.

Attempts to Fix:

Removed and recreated the data directory.
Ran mysqld --initialize-insecure --datadir=C:/xampp/mysql/data.
Error persists when trying to connect to MySQL using mysql -u root.

What can I do to successfully initialize and start MySQL in XAMPP on my Windows 11 machine? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Why are you scrapping the mysql data directory that was created in the Install?

--initialize-insecure only installs the innodb stuff but not the system tables. Therefore the server claims about missing mysql directory:
1017: Can't find file: '.\mysql\' (errno: 2 "No such file or directory")

Use mariadb_install_db command instead, as described in the Documentation

try restart xampp control panel. if mysql not start, check firewall and antivirus settings. maybe they blocking mysql. if problem still there, uninstall xampp and install again. make sure no old mysql processes running.

Avoided that! Not a great answer!
